# Лотерейный миллионер

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания, реклама

*Ежедневно в государственные лотереи выигрывает более 200 тысяч людей, из них еженедельно [лотерейными миллионерами](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp5OwKV5dYo) становятся в среднем 15 участников по всей стране.*

*Количество [лотерейных миллионеров](https://www.kompravda.eu/daily/26614/3631522/) в стране снова увеличилось.*

Вроде бы всё понятно: лотерейный миллионер — человек, который выиграл в лотерее миллион (или более). Но почему-то это словосочетание мне не нравится.
А как вы считаете — правильно ли оно? Грамотно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 2):

У существительного ***лотерея*** только одно относительное прилагательное ***лотерейный***, которое используется в различных сочетаниях: выигрыш, бум, азарт, фонд и др.,

Более редкие сочетания:  лотерейный бал, лотерейный игрок.

Поэтому ***лотерейный миллионер*** ― уже привычное выражение, даже в кавычки его уже не заключают. **Другого способа кратко обозначить игрока, выигравшего в лотерею миллион, просто нет**.

Пример:

Я же не знаю, что будет со мною через час, через минуту; я живу как **лотерейный игрок**, для которого судьба ворочает колесо с сюрпризами. [А. И. Куприн. Вечерний гость (1904)]

Слово ***лотерея*** в Петровское время было заимствовано из нидерл. loterij, где оно из фр. lotérie < итал. lottería «лотерея»[1], от lotto «доля»  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/

**ЛОТЕРЕЯ** [тэ], -и; ж. [итал. lotteria] 1. Розыгрыш различных по количеству и качеству вещей или денежных сумм по билетам одинаковой стоимости.  <**Лотерейный**, . **Л. выигрыш. Л. билет.**